# Upgrading Silverlight 4 to 5 issues - Blend libraries?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I'm upgrading project from SL 4 to 5 and having some difficulties. See screenshot:

[image]

Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity both parts of Blend 4 I beleive. Where do I find proper counterparts that I can use?

Comment: Those are expression blend libraries that don't work for SL5. And there is no Expression Blend 5. So, I'm not sure if I can upgrade at all

Comment: OK, so what error are you getting? How do you know that the libraries "don't work"?

Comment: I used to upgrade 5 version blend worked well for me. Sure I dont know what you used in your project. But as if some libraries missing. Can it be your blend dll's path changed? Beside this I had other problems with 5 version and stayed on 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install [Expression Blend Preview for Silverlight 5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9503). Then update your references.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

(Note: even though it's a "preview" edition, it's fully functional as far as I can tell. The only limitation is that it can only be used for Silverlight 5.)

Update:
From the EULA:

> i. Right to Use and Distribute.
>
> The code and text files listed below are “Distributable Code.”
>
> · REDIST.TXT Files. You may copy and distribute the object code form of code listed in REDIST.TXT files.

redist.en.txt:

> Expression Blend SDK for Silverlight 4
>
> =====================================================
>
> The following list is a list of files available with the Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Silverlight 4 software for redistribution under the Expression Blend SDK for Silveright 4 license.
>
> Subject to the license terms for the software, you may redistribute the files contained in the following directories unmodified as a part of your programs:
>
> Libraries
>
> Templates
>
> {Program Files}\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\

Update 2: Redist.en.txt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v5.0) says:

> Expression Blend SDK Preview for Silverlight 5
>
> =====================================================
>
> The following list is a list of files available with the Microsoft Expression Blend SDK Preview for Silverlight 5 software for redistribution under the Expression Blend Preview for Silveright 5 license.
>
> Subject to the license terms for the software, you may redistribute the files contained in the following directories unmodified as a part of your programs:
>
> ---
>
> Libraries
>
> Templates
>
> {Program Files}\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v5.0\

Comment: But is it fine to deploy in production?

Comment: @katit: updated my answer. The EULA still refers to Silverlight 4, but I'm guessing that's an oversight.